# Graph of Second-Order Circuit

Tags: voltage, current

I know that a circuit is second-order circuit if there are two storage elements.
I used pspice to simulate [image: RLC Parallel?]

and I got this graph[image: v_O (t) vs t>=0+]

I feel like it is not correct.
Please tell me my mistake.

when there is only L present, the graph would look like this:
[image]

when there is only C present, the graph would look like this:
[image]

Comment: Well, what don't you like about it?  Let's see at 1 us the voltage looks to still be rising.  What's going on?  Hey try this, what would happen with just the L or just the C?  What's V1?  (5V?)

Comment: v1 = 10V. I would like to know if the graph makes sense.

Comment: OK none of those look right.  (unless you've specified that the initial voltage on the cap is 10 V.)   So there is some mistake.  (You do know what the RC charging waveform should look like?,  with 500 ohm and 10nF that a time of 5 us.)

Comment: I figure it out. I need to fix the parameter inside the voltage source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the voltage source to Vpulse, and the parameters in the Vpulse to:

```
V1=0
V2=10V
TD=1n
TR=1n
TF=1n
PW=10n
PER=10
```